# Removing index.php from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the following .htaccess file in my subdomain. 
My website has `http://hello/forum/index.php`, and would like to hide this index.php file, and make it `http://hello/forum`.

Whenever I use the attached .htaccess, it directs to `http://hello`, not `http://hello/forum`. Am I missing something?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) forum/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(forum)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work... Do I also need to check http://hello 's htaccess file too?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

in .htaccess file.